# Powershell: Get network login history of past 90 days

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get all **network login history of the past 90 days**.

So far, I've got these 2 commands but they still don't give me what I want and I'm asking for help here.

1. Below gives me only the network login history. One problem is it's giving me the data for only today and yesterday, although the command doesn't have any date restriction.

> Get-WinEvent -ProviderName 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'
> -FilterXPath "*[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType']='3']]"

2. Below gives me data going back a few more days only, although it's supposed to be the past 90 days.

> Get-Eventlog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -After
> (Get-Date).AddDays(-90);

What I'm looking for would be something like a combined command of the two commands above. I tried combining those two commands in various ways but couldn't make it work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are searching the windows event logs with those commands, how far back do the logs actually go if you use eventviewer? You can only search as far back as the log goes.

Comment: Looks like my System log goes up to about a week. (Oldest log shows 4/30/2021) But, I definitely had a lot more logins (id 4624 for logons) during the past week.

Comment: FWIW `LogonType = 3` is a Network Logon - won't show you local console logins, you'll want `LogonType = 2` for that. It doesn't matter how far back the System log channel goes, the Audit events are stored in the Security log channel (separate logs, separate files on disk)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I know and I don't need to check local console logins because I'm just checking users' network-based login history (type 3) on servers in data centers where users cannot get in. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can list 2 providers in the filterhashtable.  This should work in powershell 7.  I don't have that auditing turned on.  In powershell 5 you can only say `data=3` (2?).  You can also pipe to `format-table -groupby logname`, although the header still says providername.

```
get-winevent @{providername = 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing',
  'Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon'; logontype = 3; starttime = (get-date).AddDays(-90)}
```